# Not able to loop through all the elements using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement where I need to process a piece of XML and find out all the address and phone element and print them out.

The XML and the XSL that I am using can be found here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSp/2

I am able to get all the addresses, however, I am not able to get all the phone numbers. It only prints the first phone number available.

The current output I am getting is:

```
<person:Party>
            <party:Address>
                <add:AddressLine1>101 S PLAZA PL</add:AddressLine1>
                <add:AddressTypeCode>Billing Address</add:AddressTypeCode>
                <add:City>ABSECON</add:City>
                <add:State>NJ</add:State>
                <add:PostalCode>08201-1306</add:PostalCode>
            </party:Address>
            <party:Phone>
                <phn:PhoneNumber>952-7041821</phn:PhoneNumber>
                <phn:Extension/>
                <phn:PhoneType>Billing Phone</phn:PhoneType>
            </party:Phone>
            <party:Address>
                <add:AddressLine1>101 S PLAZA PL</add:AddressLine1>
                <add:AddressTypeCode>Home Address</add:AddressTypeCode>
                <add:City>ABSECON</add:City>
                <add:State>NJ</add:State>
                <add:PostalCode>08201-1306</add:PostalCode>
            </party:Address>
            <party:Phone>
                <phn:PhoneNumber>952-7041821</phn:PhoneNumber>
                <phn:Extension/>
                <phn:PhoneType>Billing Phone</phn:PhoneType>
            </party:Phone>
        </person:Party>
```

Here the same phone number and the type is coming in both the places under party:Phone. But I need both the phone and type to be printed. Something like the below:

```
<person:Party>
                <party:Address>
                    <add:AddressLine1>101 S PLAZA PL</add:AddressLine1>
                    <add:AddressTypeCode>Billing Address</add:AddressTypeCode>
                    <add:City>ABSECON</add:City>
                    <add:State>NJ</add:State>
                    <add:PostalCode>08201-1306</add:PostalCode>
                </party:Address>
                <party:Phone>
                    <phn:PhoneNumber>952-7041821</phn:PhoneNumber>
                    <phn:Extension/>
                    <phn:PhoneType>Billing Phone</phn:PhoneType>
                </party:Phone>
                <party:Address>
                    <add:AddressLine1>101 S PLAZA PL</add:AddressLine1>
                    <add:AddressTypeCode>Home Address</add:AddressTypeCode>
                    <add:City>ABSECON</add:City>
                    <add:State>NJ</add:State>
                    <add:PostalCode>08201-1306</add:PostalCode>
                </party:Address>
                <party:Phone>
                    <phn:PhoneNumber>952-7041822</phn:PhoneNumber>
                    <phn:Extension/>
                    <phn:PhoneType>Home Phone</phn:PhoneType>
                </party:Phone>
            </person:Party>
```

It will be really helpful if someone can share the logic of how to get all the phone numbers and their respective type to be printed. And the `Billing Phone` details should come under the `Billing Address` `party:Address` block and `Home Phone` details also follow the same and come under the `Home Address` `party:Address` block

**Note:** For ease of the purpose I have hard coded the memberId in the XSL given `<xsl:variable name="memberId" select="'2cd76ea8-825c-432e-af6d-92a133fb8fc0'"/>` 
However, in real scenario I'll be taking all the memberId available in the XML and process the same logic on them to get the phone number and type.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this **(very much) simplified** example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx"
exclude-result-prefixes="json">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/json:object">
    <parties>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//json:array[@name='contacts']"/>
    </parties>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:array[@name='contacts']">
    <party id="{.//json:string[@name='contactId']}">
        <billing>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//json:array[@name='addresses']/json:object[json:string[@name='addressType']='Billing Address']" mode="address"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//json:array[@name='phones']/json:object[json:string[@name='phoneType']='Billing Phone']" mode="phone"/>
        </billing>
        <home>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//json:array[@name='addresses']/json:object[json:string[@name='addressType']='Home Address']" mode="address"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//json:array[@name='phones']/json:object[json:string[@name='phoneType']='Home Phone']" mode="phone"/>
        </home>
    </party>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:object" mode="address">
    <address>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json:string"/>
    </address>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:object" mode="phone">
    <phone>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json:string"/>
    </phone>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:string">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSp/4

Comment: This is correct, but the structure is bit different. Also, I have other things that needs to be done in the same XSL, so I can not change the XSL now. I am just looking for a correct XPATH to get the phone details as given in my expected output.

Comment: I am using the XML provided by you - and I am definitely getting all the phone details from that input. More importantly, I am getting the billing phone/s to follow the billing address/es and the home phone/s to follow the home address/s - which to me seems the more difficult problem here.